# RegisterValue - <> in name

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I have this piece of code:

```
<Component Id="defaultInstallDirRegistry_component" Guid='{XXXXXX}'>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\ExchangeDatabase" Name="<default>" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" KeyPath='yes' />
</Component>
```

but when I try to compile ti

> error CNDL0104 : Not a valid source file; detail: '<', hexadecimal
>   value 0x3c, is an invalid character.

I know that  cause a problem but do not know how to solve it... I tried use CDATA but it does not help...

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use the standard XML entity encoding for the '<' character since that is the core issue in this situation.
Change: 'Name="<default>" '
To:     'Name="&lt;default>" '     (will work, and is easy for humans to read)
Or to:  'Name="&lt;default&gt;" '  (for more consistent reading)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so solution to this problem is use notation &#x3c ; (without whitespace) so if you want to write such a character just use notation &#xNNNN where NNNN is hexa code of your char...